# Open the web page and jump to the URL of an app in AppGallery

Tags: android, browser, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

I want to open a link in the Huawei browser, and then automatically jump to the AppGallery where my app is located.How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General:

```
market://details?id={packageName}
```

for example,

```
<a href="market://details?id=com.tencent.mobileqq">Jump</a>
```

Huawei：

```
hiapplink://com.huawei.appmarket?appId={appId}
```

for example, `<a href="hiapplink://com.huawei.appmarket?appId=C9319">Jump</a>`